# Formating by column header instead of alphabet

Tags: excel, vba, rpa, uipath-studio

I want to do some column formatting but column position is changing every time so how can i use column header instead of Column Alphabet ?

```
Sub Excel_Format()
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use Names in Excel to define unique names for cells, ranges, rows, columns. You can also use "real tables" and refer to table headers instead of column ranges

Comment: Can you please Edit this code as per my requirement

Comment: @pravinbindage, you'd better give more info as to how _"column position is changing every time"_

Comment: @user3598756 It is quite common that Excel sheets are dynamic and that column positions are moved due to added/removed columns to the left. I rarely use static references (e.g. "A1") to ranges when using VBA. That's what I guess is meant by "column positions is changing". If you delete column G, then Column J will become Column I. That's the problem in this case... I guess

Comment: @Gowire, rest sure that, after 25+years of Excel VBA coding, I know that. I was asking for more detail about the criteria of the columns change. Let's see what pravin will answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to start defining a Name for your column. The quickest way to do it is to select the column (Column J in this case) and enter a name in the range/cell selector on the top-left part of your Workbook. See image below:

[image]

I have named the column to "MyColumn". You can now use this as a reference in your code, like this:

```
Sub Excel_Format()
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("MyColumn")
    Rng.NumberFormat = "0"
    Rng.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Even if you add or remove columns to the left of column J, the reference to MyColumn will remain correct

Comment: it throws error _ Type Mismatch  on this line -> Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Columns("MyColumn")

Comment: @pravinbindage Ah, sorry... A quick copy/paste error. It should be `Range` instead of `Column`. The code is corrected now

Comment: now it throw another error - application defined 0r object defined error

Comment: @pravinbindage Have you defined the name for your column? It must be the same as in the VBA code.

Comment: Yes i defined that

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way. You can use it for any header, only adapting the used constant:

```
Sub Excel_Format()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, RngH As Range
    Const myColName As String = "ColumnX" 'your column header
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
    
    Set RngH = ws.rows(1).Find(myColName)
    If Not RngH Is Nothing Then
        With RngH.EntireColumn
            .NumberFormat = "0"
            .AutoFit
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox myColName & " could not be found in the sheet first row..."
    End If
End Sub
```

The header should exist **in the first sheet row**. If not, you should adapt `ws.rows(1).Find(` writing the necessary row, instead of `...

Selecting, activating in such a context only consumes Excel resources, not bringing any benefit.